# Is there a way to pass an array of values into an IN clause in Databricks Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, databricks

I have an array column in Table A, and I want to select all rows in Table B where one of the values match one of the values in the array from Table A.

Code would look something like this:

```
WITH table_a AS (
SELECT 
id, 
array('cat','dog') AS animals
) 

SELECT b.*
FROM table_b b 
  JOIN table_a a 
    ON a.id = b.id 
    AND b.animal_type IN (b.animals)
```

Comment: `AND b.animal_type IN (b.animals)` I assume that should be `AND b.animal_type IN (a.animals)` i.e. the second column reference is from a

Comment: LOL the more things change the more they stay the same

Answer (score 0):

In general you should be able to explode the array to form rows that may be used via `IN()` e.g.

```
with table_a as (
SELECT explode(array('value1', 'value2', 'value3')) AS my_value
)

SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE column_name IN (SELECT my_value FROM table_a);
```

However in the case you have suggested it isn't known how you would align the id's between tables A and B i.e. the join condition `ON a.id = b.id` presents a problem for which we have no information.

Note according to [this databricks reference](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/explode.html) you may need to use explode this way:

```
with table_a as (
SELECT my_value FROM explode(array('value1', 'value2', 'value3')) AS t(my_value)
)
```

Comment: Thevanswer is No in reality.

Answer (score 0):

No, this type of feature is not possible, provided.